# How to use CountDownTimer in my android application?

Tags: android, timer

I'm writing a android application. I have a CountDownTimer in between my application and i want until the timer to zero, all my app run(user must be select the true Button) and when become zero and the user did'nt anything, the other action performed (the user loses).

this is CountDownTimer :

```
    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            a.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            /*while (millisUntilFinished / 1000 != 1) {

            }*/
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            a.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();
```

and this is part of code:

```
  if ((randomAndroidColor1 == rainbow[0]) {
        findViewById(ans).setBackgroundColor(rainbow2[0]);

        findViewById(ans).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                c3.setBackgroundColor(rainbow1[2]);
            }
        });
    }
```

How to access to millisUntilFinished variable in above if condition?
Timer and if condition worked correctly but I want to combine them.

Comment: Can you give more details? What you want exactly and what is that rainbow arrays?

Comment: yes rainbow is array of colors. user must be choose corrct color between 3 colors(According to a specific logic). and it must be done in 5 seconds otherwise loses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly , you can use an instance boolean variable.

```
 boolean isWon = false;
private void countDown() {
    isWon=false;  // Reset every method call.

    // Set listener once in  method.
    findViewById(R.id.answer).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            isWon=true;
        }
    });


    new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // onTick works.
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            if(isWon){
                // Won
            }else{
                // Lose
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```